# Display tag excerpt on hover when editing questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, editing, tag-excerpt, user-interface

While editing question, sometimes one needs to check that the correct tags are present.

Sometimes one needs to check the tag information in order to say it is relevant or not.

So, for checking that, would it be nice, if the tag details appear on hover, while editing?

Comment: +1, I have been annoyed by the lack of this feature too.

Comment: since that would be a SE-network-wide change, I think the place to ask would be meta.stackexchange

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b.   Just did a quick check.

Seems like it already exist.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/display-tag-excerpt-tooltips-when-editing-a-question

Comment: @Glen_b, been through the above meta link. But, I couldn't find any such feature (didn't find it in any stackexchange site, including SO)

Comment: I believe that this is not implemented anywhere (at least not quite as you describe) ... which is why I explained that the place to *ask* for it would be meta.SE ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really find  [this thread on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168035/display-tag-excerpt-tooltips-when-editing-a-question) useful. Maybe the feature has been discontinued and/or because the thread is outdated (2014).

However, I have found a temporary solution, which might help address the problem for the time being. As @amoeba has mentioned, this is a very common problem, and displaying tag excerpts would really help people while editing questions, for tagging and untagging relevant tags.

Upon clicking on a particular tag, it gets flattened and then the excerpt gets displayed, as shown in the screenshot below (<-- which have been captured today 02 Sept. '15)
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: That (backspacing to bring up the tag info) is something works for me just fine here and on CV.  It may require some minimum level of privilege perhaps.

Comment: The whole discussion on that meta link is about people ranting about the feature, and yet it's not back.  Not sure about the reputation requirements, as I could do that on the **Workplace** community too, where I have a rep of 101.

Comment: It looks like it works [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLop6.png)

Comment: Yes, it works everywhere. But, I'm saying that I'm not sure about the privileges part.